# Docker Compose: delay starting of the containers created from same image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, parallel-processing, containers

Below is snip of the docker compose file.

```yaml
service:
  image: xxxxx:latest
  restart: always
  deploy:
     replicas: 2
```

I want to run two instances of the same image and delay the start of the containers. For example: Lets say Container2 should start 30s later than container1. How can i achieve this?

I tried this below code. But it is for updating the containers late and not to delay the start.

```yaml
service:
  image: xxxxx:latest
  restart: always
  deploy:
     replicas: 2
     update_config:
        delay: 30s
```

Any idea how can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you try adding 30s sleep in the entry point of your other service to delay the actual process starting.

Comment: Why 30 seconds exactly?  Is there some other signal you could look for, like a health check in the first container passing?

Comment: 30 seconds just randomly. Lets say delay by 'X' seconds

Comment: Are you looking to delay the start of the second xxxxx:latest instance while having the first run normally?

Comment: Yes. So basically, I want to analyse few files. If i start the two containers at same time, they are picking same files, analysing and writing to same row in the postgreSQL database table, which is leading to deadlock. I have put a condition that once the files are picked, those files status should be changed from 'available' to 'in progress', so that other containers wont pick the same. But unfortunately it is not working. I am thinking that delaying might help so that the files picked up by container1 wont be picked up by container 2. Same like how pods work in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

A delayed start for the second instance may help but it doesn't sound like it would really solve the problem; the instances can end up competing due to execution timing. For example, the first file takes 2:00 minutes to process, and the second takes 1:30 to process - leading to contention again (I'm ignoring other factors). The main problem appears to be database contention leading to deadlock

Below I suggest a re-work of the SQL and your code. Since I don't know what you're using for code, I'm suggesting SQL commands that should resolve the deadlock. Most DB deadlocks can be resolved by restructuring the SQL statements (by providing additional context in SQL queries, and other techniques)

Addressing a solution through SQL: I'm going to assume a table name of `work_files` throughout, along with assumed column names - you'll need to change the SQL to fit your situation

**NOTE**: when specifying variables in dynamically generated queries, you should use [dymaic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-dynamic.html). If you don't, you can be opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks

Selecting what to work on:

```sql
-- Chose a file (put the returned ID and path into variables)
SELECT id, path FROM work_files WHERE status='available' LIMIT 1;
```

Set the status to 'in progress' if it is still 'available':

```sql
--- Assuming file_id is returned ID from previous query
UPDATE work_files SET status='in progress' WHERE id=file_id AND status='available'
```

You can check the result of the above query to see if the row was changed. If not, then loop back to the first query to select another file. Keep looping until you get something that isn't being worked on or you have finished processing files

Finally, to mark as complete:

```sql
-- Ignoring current status value here since we should "own" this row
UPDATE work_files SET status='completed' WHERE id=file_id
```

The following query doesn't help since the other instance could have gotten the file before the current instance did - you get a false positive

```sql
-- Don't use this
-- This can't detect the case where the other instance got there first
SELECT * FROM work_files WHERE path=file_path AND status='in progress' AND id=file_id
```